# jQuery - Referring to nearby elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

When the value of the 'product-input' changes, I want the 'product-total' to update.  I have the event working, but I can't seem to refer to the 'product-total'.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class='product'>
    <h2>Photo Prints up to 5” x 7”</h2>
    <div class='product-total'></div>
        <div class='choices'>
        <input type='text' class='raw standard product-input'  />
    </div> <!-- END Choices -->

    Standard: <input type='radio' class='quality standard' value='standard' />
    Full: <input type='radio' class='quality full' value='full' />

</div> <!-- END Product -->
```

And the jQuery:

```
jQuery('input.product-input').change(function() {
        jQuery('div.product-total', jQuery(this).parent('div.product')).html(total);

    });
```

Comment: try:
jQuery('input.product-input').change(function() {
        jQuery('div.product-total').html(total);

    });

Comment: parent of product-total is the ``<div class='choices'>`` To get the product-total you need to the previous element: ``$(this).parent().prev()`` then you can set the html or text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
jQuery(this).parent('div.product')
```

With:

```
jQuery(this).closest('div.product')
```

- `parent` goes only one level up.
- `closest` goes up until it finds the first match.

Full code:

```
jQuery(this).closest('div.product').find('div.product-total').html(total);
```

`find` is better than a context selector because actually `find` is what context selector uses, so you can use it at the first place and save that trip.

Answer (score 0):

I post it as an answer so it's clearer.
Try this:

```
  jQuery('input.product-input').change(function() {
     jQuery('div.product-total').html(total);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery try changing this

jQuery('div.product-total', jQuery(this).parent('div.product')).html(total);

To this (I've used the $ syntax but it's use is irrelevant to function)

$(this).closest('div.product').find('product-total').html(total);

... and make sure total is populated.

Comment: What is `($ syntax irrelevant)` ?!

Comment: I replaced use of jQuery with $ as the shortcut syntax since it is my personal preference but does not affect the function of the code.  Sorry for the lack of formatting, I'm on a mobile device at the moment.